# Execute apache camel route scheduler with multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-camel

I created new apache camel route scheduler and I want to be invoked by multiple threads on an interval. want to execute x number of threads. I am unsure how to go about it

```
public class TestRoute extends RouteBuilder {

private TestProperties properties;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("scheduler://testScheduler" +
        "?delay=5000" +
        "&poolSize=3")
        .routeId("testRoute")
        .startupOrder(1)
        .process(this::printLog);
}

private void printLog(Exchange exchange) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    log.info("Start route");
}
```

}

I used now apache camel 4.0.2

```
implementation "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot:4.0.2"
implementation "org.apache.camel.springboot:camel-spring-boot-starter:4.0.2"
```

In application logs

```
2023-11-06 14:21:29,639 INFO com.test.routes.TestRoute [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - scheduler://testScheduler] [] [Test,,,] Start route
2023-11-06 14:21:39,655 INFO com.test.routes.TestRoute [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - scheduler://testScheduler] [] [Test,,,] Start route
2023-11-06 14:21:49,663 INFO com.test.routes.TestRoute [Camel (camel-1) thread #1 - scheduler://testScheduler] [] [Test,,,] Start route
```

In older version 2.25.4 multi-threading works fine